# Does the photon propagator see the $Z$ boson propagator pole?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, standard-model, greens-functions, propagator, electroweak

As I understand, the $Z$ boson (as it decays) has a pole in its propagator that is somewhere in the complex plane, shifted off the real line. Now, suppose that I look at the full (interacting) photon propagator. This means I should calculate something like a sum over self-energy diagrams:

[image: self-energy-diagram]

It seems to me then that there is a subset of these diagrams where we get a $Z$ boson propagator as such:

[image]

for instance, you can get a $\gamma \to \bar{\psi}\psi \to Z \to \cdots \to Z \to \bar{\psi} \psi \to \gamma$. By summing up all these diagrams, it seems to me that the pole structure of the $Z$ boson is inherited by the photon, in other words you will see the same complex pole in the photon propagator. It seems to me this is only possible because the $Z,\gamma$ share same quantum numbers, and that there are interactions that allow (off-shell) things like $\gamma \to Z$ to happen.

Is this true? Or is there some kind of cancellation that happens?

Comment: what about  charge conservation, muon number conservation, the enormous difference in the coupling constants between weak and electromagnetic and the huge mass of the Z?

Comment: @annav I'm not sure I follow your comment - what difference in charge is there between Z and gamma? And what does muon number have to do with it? Fundamentally, are you claiming that the (interacting) photon propagator does *not* have the Z pole in it?

Comment: The muon is a charged particle, the muon neutrino neutral. charge does not disappear in the lines of feynman diagrams, there should be other vertices.

Comment: @annav sorry, are you referring to the $\mu, \nu$ labelled in my first diagram? That is the diagram for the photon self-energy diagram used to calculate the propagator, the $\mu,\nu$ I drew are labelling the lorentz-indices of the photon propagator, they are not labelling the edges of the feynman diagram

Comment: ok, then if it is photon to photn the charge conservation holds ,but in the loops , the photon does not have a simple vertex with the Z, the photon only couples electromagnetically. It could go to an e+e- loop in higher order corrections, or a W+W-, and then the mass of the W in the propagator makes it very low probability.addition with respect to an e+e- loop and the more loops the higher order is the correction due to the 1/137 coupling constant of em

Comment: Are you reading [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/0003-4916(82)90339-6)?

Comment: [This](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.70.3193) might be easier to read...